# Hide Keyboard when Button Click (Fragment)

Tags: android, keyboard

i got error to implement hide keyboard when button click, anyone know how to fix that?
actually code error in getSystemService and getWindowsToken

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculator, container, false);

        Button hitung = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hitung);
        final EditText height = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.height);
        final EditText weight = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.weight);

        InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(EditText.getWindowToken(), 0);

        final TextView result = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.result);
        final TextView finalresult = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.finalresult);
        finalresult.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        hitung.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            ..........
}
```

Comment: Could we get any stack print, error code in the logcat?

Comment: Hi, im not running yet, bc error still appear, on getSystemService warning said : `cannot resolve method getSystemService(Java.Lang.String)`

Comment: Is the missing '(' in this line a mistake? InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are using `Fragment` so write like `getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)`

Reason for the same :

> An Activity extends Context, a Fragment does not. Hence, you first need to get a reference to the Activity in which the Fragment is contained

**Edit**

for the other error you mentioned in the comment you can use

`getView().getWindowToken()`

and the hide method should be called inside your `button's` `onClick()` method like

`imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);`

Comment: and for `getWindowsToken()` ? warning said: cannot be reference from a static context

Comment: you can use `getView().getWindowToken()`

Comment: Thanks Its Work for me :)

Answer (score 6):

use this,

```
 public static void hideKeyboard(Context mContext) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(((Activity) mContext).getWindow()
            .getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: hmmm its like my keyboard hide forever from im start my apps

Comment: call this method on your button click. it's working and tested. @F_X

Comment: @F_X: please accept my answer if it's helpful to you.

Comment: already put in onclick method and run too, but remove `static` and keyboard stll not hide after button click, and keyboard will hide when im click `done` on keyboard numeric

Answer (score 1):

use below code

```
 try {
                    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   if(net.one97.paytm.common.utility.CJRAppCommonUtility.isDebug) e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// hide keyboard
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Context context, View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    if(inputMethodManager != null && inputMethodManager.isActive())
    {
        //inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        //InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  hitung.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
             InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
             imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well in **Koltin** you can do it like..

```
    fun View.hideKeyboard() {
        val imm =  getSystemService(context, 
        InputMethodManager::class.java) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
    }
```

call this extension function form any view any time when you want to hide keyboard when it is clicked !